# Mail app never syncs automatically

Tags: email, stock-email-app, imap

Despite setting a sync schedule for my my account in the mail app, it has never performed a sync automatically.  New mail is only ever fetched when I open the app, and pull down to refresh.  When I open the app, the "Last synced" note also shows the time I last synced it myself, which might be a whole day ago.

Using the stock mail app on a Galaxy A5 2017, though this also happened on my Galaxy S6.

The account is using IMAP.  I've tried deleting and re-adding the account and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

What version of your Android.? 
Marshmallow? Then my suspect is doze mode are intercept everything when screen off in favour to save some juice (battery) to last little longer.

Comment: Currently on 7 (Nougat).  Also happened on 6 (Marshmallow)